# how to create a currency exchange rate attribute for some products

Tags: currency

I want to create a attribute (price attribute, i think) to convert the price of some products from Euro in RON (romanian currency), in the back end.
I have default/only currency in RON, but some suppliers have reference price in euro.
So, i want to imput the price in euro (not for all products), and the attribute must convert from Euro in RON, like 1 Euro is 4.52 RON.
Or the attribute to multiply the price with 4.52, and the catalog price will be only in RON currency.

Any advices ?
Thank you,

Comment: Those products with price in EURO will be having variable price according to the fluctuation in exchange rates between EURO and RON. I'd suggest storing them in custom attribute as you already figured and the initiating a cron job to convert them into RON via some external web-service and then storing the actual price in RON. This will require creation of a module and an integration with some external exchange rate web-service if you are not willing to open your site for EURO currency.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't know very well to create this attribute. i can put the the currency / value of Euro, weekly. i don't need to integrate exchange rate web-service. if this is possible just with prices attribute it will be perfect.

Comment: Does your suppliers have direct access to Magento backend ? How do you import those products ?